# Airflow distributed model services

Tags: celery, airflow, flower

Switching from `localexecutor` to `celeryexecutor`.

In this model, I have

```
Masternode1 - airflow webserver, airflow scheduler, rabbitmq 
Masternode2 - airflow webserver, rabbitmq
Workernode1 - airflowworker
Workernode2 - airflowworker
Workernode3 - airflowworker
```

**Question:**

Where does the `Flower` service run for celery? Is it required to run that in all nodes or just any one of the nodes (since its only a UI)

Is there any other components trivial to manage a production workload ?

Is using `Kafka` for broker a reality and available to use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Celery Flower is yet another (optional) service that you may want to independently either on a dedicated machine, or share one machine among few Airflow services.
You may, for an example, run the webserver and flower on one machine, scheduler and few Airflow workers each on a dedicated machine.

Kafka as broker for Celery is something people talk about quite a lot but as far as I know there is no concrete work in Celery for it. However, considering there is [an interest to have Kafka support in Kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/301), I would assume that the moment Kombu gets Kafka support, Celery soon follow as Kombu is the core Celery dependency.